# Raspberry Pi 3 and LED connections

Tags: raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I have installed Windows 10 IOT Core on my Raspberry Pi 3.I wanted to display a scrolling text on a led display using this library.
I have a led panel display with pin configuration as shown in the attached image.I wanted to connect Raspberry Pi 3 to this led panel.Can somebody tell me how to connect the same or provide me with a diagram showing the connections.

[image]

Thanks,

Debasish

Comment: What is your LED display model? There will be a specific connection mode based on different types. Product instruction can help explain how to connect the GPIO pin on Raspberry Pi to LED pin.

Comment: The LED model is C5-4X8V1.0  http://arduino.ru/forum/apparatnye-voprosy/led-matrix-32x16-c5-4x8v10-dual-color-rg and I bought it from https://www.aliexpress.com/item/40-inch-101cm-ios-And-Android-Wifi-wireless-remote-Programmable-Advertising-LED-Display-Board-Bright-Red/32752577115.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.F3UzUv @MichaelXu-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

Take a look over [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/32x16-LED-Matrix-Panel-and-Arduino/). This is an example to connect your matrix with an Arduino. Of course it is not 1/1 suitable, but a digital output stays digital outputs. Over [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/connecting-a-16x32-rgb-led-matrix-panel-to-a-raspberry-pi/wiring-the-display) you'll find an example of an other 16x32 display with the RPi3. You can made your own layout based on these two examples. You can probably also check the open source code over [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/connecting-a-16x32-rgb-led-matrix-panel-to-a-raspberry-pi/testing), where an 16x32 display is programmed, to get the software part up and running. Good luck!

[image]

> A, B, C, D - row select with 74HC138
>
> OE - 74HC595 Ouput Enable(Active Low)
>
> STB - 74HC595 Strobe / Data Latch
>
> CLK - 74HC595 Clock Input
>
> R - data input for 74HC595 (RED section / 4*74HC595)
>
> G - data input for 74HC595 (GREEN section / 4*74HC595)